# MongoDB - simulate a transaction

Tags: mongodb

I would like to simulate a transaction on MongoDB and you wonder if there is a better solution. I have a document that has inside an array. I would like to increase the values ​​of this. But if at the same time another user selects the document with the same values, result wrong data. Must wait until the update is resolved, and only after another user may request the document and he also increase the arry. 
Any sugestion?

Thankyou

Comment: I recommend you to read **'Mimicking Transactional Behavior'** from **'Mongodb Applied Design Patterns'** and in your case you could read **'Optimistic Update with Compensation'** section of this book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let mongo handle these issues of concurrency. It knows how to handle situations like this and each update will be atomic.

Instead of submitting the actual value to be updated you can specify only the amount you want to increment. I would suggest using the appropriate operators to allow mongo to do its work. If all you are doing is an increment on a value, you can use the [`$inc` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

Taken from the linked documentation:

> The `$inc` operator increments a field by a specified value and has the following form:
>
> ```
> { $inc: { <field1>: <amount1>, <field2>: <amount2>, ... } }
> ```
>
> To specify a  in an embedded document or in an array, use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation).

Note that this method will also work for decrementing the value; Just pass a negative value as the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 4.0 MongoDB will add support for multi-document transactions. 
Transactions will be multi-statement, with syntax like *start_transaction* and *commit_transaction*.

For details visit this link: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions-in-mongodb?jmp=community